# "from a import b" not working, but I can import a and then use a.b

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, python-module

## Overview

`from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch` does *not* work.

```
import elasticsearch
e = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch(...)
```

*does* work.

### Deets

I am trying to use a simple Elasticsearch client in python using AWS (ssh'd on an Amazon linux e3 machine). The code I am copying is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-request-signing.html#es-request-signing-python). I am unable to import the Elasticsearch class as described in the guide.

Using `from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch` gives me the error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'Elasticsearch'`.

I opened the python3 cli  to check it out. If I type `from elasticsearch import E` and tab-complete, I get the following suggestions: `EOFError(          Ellipsis           EnvironmentError(  Exception(`. However `from elasticsearch import Ellipsis` gives me `ImportError: cannot import name 'Ellipsis'`.

If I type `import elasticsearch`, then on the next line `elasticsearch.` and hit tab to autocomplete, I get the full range that I would expect (`Elasticsearch(`, `RequestsHttpConnection(`, etc.).

### I assume that this has something to do with the way/where it is installed.

I used `pip3 install elasticsearch --user` to install it originally. I uninstalled it (`pip3 uninstall elasticsearch`) and returned to the python cli. `from elasticsearch import E` still gives me `EOFError(          Ellipsis           EnvironmentError(  Exception(` on the tab-complete, but `from elasticsearch import Ellipsis` now returns `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'elasticsearch'`, as does just `import elasticsearch`.

Not really quite sure what is up. I did not tag this as *elasticsearch* because it might be a user error :P

- `which python3`: /usr/bin/python3
- `which pip3`: ~/.local/bin/pip3
- `pip3 --version`: pip 18.1 from /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

Comment: The import behavior you describe isn't consistent with itself, and it sounds like it may come from a mixture of different points in your process where you had different things installed or uninstalled.

Comment: Don't take the autocomplete suggestions too seriously - Python's default autocompleter isn't great. It doesn't know how to autocomplete `from` imports. IPython does a better job.

Comment: (When I say "may come from a mixture of different points in your process where you had different things installed or uninstalled", I mean more than just the part where you say you uninstalled elasticsearch. The parts in the "Deets" section don't sound consistent.)

Comment: You are right. I saw the autocomplete and it sent me in the wrong direction. I think that my problem is my main file was named 'elasticsearch.py' T-T

I think that explains the problem with the python cli as well. I thought I ran it in `~` to avoid that potential problem. Whatever, seems to work after renaming my initial file.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I had named my file the same thing as the module I was trying to import from - `elasticsearch.py`. As user2357112 states, I became hung up on the incorrect autocomplete.